# dropdown populated on basis of another using ajax in coldfusion, not working

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have searched a lot through this website and found some similar posts, but they could not help. I have 2 dropdowns. The first is populated through an inline query. The second needs to be populated through the first's selection. I know `cfselect` and `cfajaxproxy` are 2 of the simplest things, but I want to use them on Railo which doesn't support them (checked and returned disappointed).

The ajax code goes like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'admin/getModelsForManufs.cfc?method=getModels&returnFormat=JSON',
      data: {manuid:selected},
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(res) {
                  var newoptions = "";
                  for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
                      newoptions += "<option value=\"" + res[i].ID + "\">" + res[i].NAME + "</option>";
                  }
                  $("#model").append(newoptions);
              },
              error: function(x) {
                  alert(x.responseText);
              }
    });
```

Where `manuid` is the first selection, and `model` is the html field ID for second dropdown to be populated. The cfc has the following:

```
<cffunction name="getModels" access="remote" returnType="array">
    <cfargument name="manuid" type="numeric" required="true" default="#url.manuid#">

    <cfset var data="">
    <cfset var result=[]>
    <cfset var i=0>

    <cfquery name="data" datasource="#THIS.dsn#">
        select modelId, modelName 
        from   tablename
        where  manufacturerid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.manuid#">
    </cfquery>

    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#data.RecordCount#">
        <cfset model = {}> 
        <cfset model.NAME = data.modelName[i]>
        <cfset model.ID = data.modelId[i]>
        <cfset arrayAppend(result, model)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

In Firebug, the data is in the format:

```
[{"ID":84.0,"NAME":"name 1"},{"ID":1.0,"NAME":"name 2"}]
```

which looks correct and there are many more records returned. Have tried most of the tricks but still scratching my head as to why the second dropdown doesn't populate. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Default values for required fields kind of defeats the purpose of making it mandatory.  Plus, what does this function know about url?  In any event, back to basics.  Does your function work when you run it strictly with cf, ie not using ajax?

Comment: Railo doesn't support cfselect and cfajaxproxy?  Are you sure?  Check http://railodocs.org/index.cfm/tag/cfselect and http://railodocs.org/index.cfm/tag/cfajaxproxy

Comment: +1 what Dan said, make sure your cfc works before attempting it in AJAX. Secondly, you are telling AJAX that the returned `dataType` is "text", but in the URL you are specifying `returnFormat` of JSON. Change your AJAX `dataType` to "json" and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'admin/getModelsForManufs.cfc?method=getModels&returnFormat=JSON',
  data: {manuid:selected},
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(res) {
              var res2 = JSON.parse(res);
              var newoptions = "";
              for(var i=0; i<res2.length; i++) {
                  newoptions += "<option value=\"" + res2[i].ID + "\">" + res2[i].NAME + "</option>";
              }
              $("#model").append(newoptions);
          },
          error: function(x) {
              alert(x.responseText);
          }
});
```